# lncs - Changing the counter for a specific environment

Tags: environments, counters, lncs

I am using the `llncs` document class and I need to set the counter for the environment 'remark', so that when I use `\begin{remark} ... \end{remark}` I obtain *Remark 1* wherever I am in the document.

How can I do it? Is it possible to define a new counter and then force `remark` to use that one?

P.S. I **should not** define a new environment

### EDIT

I am sorry but maybe I did not explain myself very well: I do not want to **fix** the counter of the remark to be always 1. I just want it to **start** from 1, and then increase normally. So the first remark will be *Remark 1*, the second will be *Remark 2*, and so on. As it is now, it seems the remark environment is sharing the counter with theorems, corollaries, etc. and I do not want this.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,envcountsame,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\numberwithin{theorem}{section}
\numberwithin{lemma}{section}
\numberwithin{definition}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{corollary}{section}


\linespread{1.2}

\begin{document}

\section{My first section}

\begin{theorem}
Here I state a very interesting theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
Here I state a very interesting lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{definition}
Here I state a very interesting definition
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}
And here I would like to state a very interesting remark, numbered as Remark 1
\end{remark}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You want to put the counter on hold?

Comment: No,  I want everything to be "normal" but the `remark` environment to start from 1, regardless of what has already happened in the rest of the document.

Comment: I don't see a sharing with `theorem` etc. environment! `llncs` does use `\newaliascnt`, that's true, however

Comment: I neither. So make a complete example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Apparently, the `envcountsame` option is the culprit

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I know, but psst.

Comment: You are right: I am indeed using the `envcountsame` option so that I don't have a Theorem 2.1, a Lemma 2.1, a Definition 2.1, etc. But I still would like the `remark` environment to behave differently

Comment: Well as I wrote: Make a sensible minimal example. I won't spent more time trying to figure out which options you use.

Comment: @minomic: See the update of my post, on the top!

Comment: I have just added a MWE that shows the 'problem'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

If the `envcountsame` document class option is given, all `llncs` defined theorems use the `theorem` counter as shared counter.

Now, `envcountsame` enables `\newaliascnt`, defining an alias counter, which in turn checks (for this question relevant) for `\c@remark` if it already exists. In order to decouple `remark` from `theorem`, `\c@remark` must be `\relax`ed and redefined as a new counter.

```
\documentclass[envcountsame]{llncs}


\makeatletter
\if@envcntsame
\let\c@remark\relax
\newcounter{remark}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
A remark
\end{remark}

\begin{theorem}
Foo
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Another Foo
\end{theorem}
\begin{remark}
  Another remark
\end{remark}

\begin{remark}
Yet another remark
\end{remark}



\begin{remark}
And now another counter value for remark after resuming
\end{remark}


\end{document}
```

### [image]

Old stuff...

I doubt the usability of setting `remark` counter to 1, but here is a way with `\AtBeginEnvironment`

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\AtBeginEnvironment{remark}{\setcounter{remark}{0}}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
A remark
\end{remark}

\section{Foo}

\begin{remark}
  Another remark
\end{remark}

\begin{remark}
Yet  Another remark
\end{remark}


\end{document}
```

**Another possibility** using `xassoccnt` and its `Suspend` feature

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\setcounter{remark}{1} % Set it to 1 
\SuspendCounters{remark} % suspend it 

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
A remark
\end{remark}

\section{Foo}

\begin{remark}
  Another remark
\end{remark}

\begin{remark}
Yet another remark
\end{remark}

\ResumeSuspendedCounters{remark}


\begin{remark}
And now another counter value for remark after resuming
\end{remark}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `newaliascnt` solution worked perfectly for me. Than you!

Comment: @minomic: Actually, `\newaliascnt` isn't necessary at all. See the update

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a complete senseless requirement. Why using a number at all then? But if you want:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand\theremark{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{remark}
abc
\end{remark}

\begin{remark}
abc
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I did not explain the problem very well: please, see the edit in the question